# Not able to drag connect my UITextView to my custom UIView

Tags: uiview, uitextfield

I have been searching around for a while now, and I can't figure out if what I am doing is possible. I would think it is, but I am having no luck finding an example. I have a UIViewController, and nested inside that ViewController I have a UIView. I have that UIView linked up to a custom UIView class. Nested inside the UIView is a UITextField. I am trying to drag connect the UITextField to the UIViews.h file. Xcode won't let this happen, so I am trying to figure out if this is possible.

I am able to call a method inside my UIView from my UIViewController, so I think it's all wired up correctly.

Thanks

Comment: This is possible. Did you set the custom class in the Identity inspector in .xib file?

Comment: u said `UIView.h` file ?? OMG. that's not possible. u can't edit the framework file bro. Do it in your custom file please.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add class by clicking file-add file?Try to relaunch xcoode.

Comment: I used the "+" button at the bottom of the file structure window and created the new class from there, and saved it into the project.

Comment: Oddly enough. I have discovered that I can drag connect from connection inspector to the storyboard, but not the other way around....